# How to train a model in sklearn with a feature column containing vectors instead of scalars?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, word-embedding

Say I had a dataset containing days of the week: sat, sun, mon, etc.

I used the technique of replacing categories with their embeddings. Whereas before I would have transformed the “days of week” feature using 1-hot encoding, entity embeddings get me a vector for each day.

How can I use these vectors in my model?

Similar question applies to an NLP classification task. Say before I would have one hot encoded all the words in my vocabulary, so each column corresponds to a word. Now I have vectors representing each word. How does this change a model? Do I need to feed a 3D tensor to, say, logistic regression?

Answer (score 1):

You should represent one row as one vector, that can be simply done by concatenating lists. I suppose you using pandas DataFrame, so the code example can look like this:

```
X_train_full = []

for i, index in enumerate(X_train.index):
    embeddings = calculate_embeddings(X_train.loc[index, 'SOME_COLUMN'])
    X_train_full.append(np.concatenate([X_train.values[i], embeddings]))
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. My data will have features other than just a single categorical variable. For example, I might have “age, price, day of week.” Those are three scalar values in each row. Now if I convert day of week to a vector containing embeddings, are you saying I just concat the vector to age and price columns? If my day of week vector is of length 3, then my new feature matrix is age+price+dow_vector=5 columns per row?

Comment: Exactly! Your example is correct. Imagen what will be if you just do OneHotEncoding for the column "day_of_week". Here is an example from the sklearn documentation regarding "Column Transformer with Mixed Types": https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html